# Finding the solution set of the equation $\frac{2(2x+3)}{x+1}-\frac{2}{x+1}+3=0,x\in\mathbb R$

Tags: solution-verification, set-theory, roots, quadratics

**Question**

Which of the following is an empty set?

A) The set of prime numbers which are even.

B) The solution set of the equation $\frac{2(2x+3)}{x+1}-\frac{2}{x+1}+3=0,x\in\mathbb R$

C) $(A\times B)\cap(B\times A),$ where A and B are disjoint.

D) The set of reals which satisfy $x^2+ix+i-1=0$

(The answer given is C))

**My Attempt:**

I think the answer should be B), C), D).

Regarding option B)

$$\frac{4x+6-2}{x+1}+3=0\\4+3=0$$

Regarding D)

$x=\frac{-i\pm\sqrt{-1-4i+4}}2$

Please confirm.

Comment: For D, trying simplifying $\sqrt{-1-4i+4}$.

Comment: $x=-1$ satisfies thye equation in (D)

Comment: @L.F. got it, thanks. $x=-1$ satisfies the equation. Can you also comment about B?

Comment: @aarbee I'm not sure about B — I would pick B and C.  The only possible counterargument I can think of is that the equation in B is technically undefined when $x = -1$, which is different from it being false, so a strict interpretation of B might conclude that B is undefined rather than the empty set, but that seems overly pedantic.

Comment: For $C$ , $(a, b) =(b, a) $ iff $a=b$ . Given $A, B$ disjoint. Hence $C$ is true.

Comment: @L.F. thankyou ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A) is obviously nonempty since $2$ is in the set.

B) $x=-1$ is clearly not acceptable as a solution, since the equation is not defined at $x=-1$. Now assuming $x\neq-1$. Then we get $7x=-7$ which gives $x=-1$, contradiction. Therefore here we have an empty set.

C)If we assume that there is an $(a,b)$ in $(AXB)\bigcap(BXA)$ then $(a,b)$ is in $AXB$ and in $(BXA)$ i.e $a$ is in $A$ and $B$, contradiction. Here the set is empty

D)The set is nonempty since for $x=-1$ the equation is satisfied!

So I only disagree with the answer in (B)!!

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773)